# Why did I fail this audit?

Tags: support, reviewing, review-audits

I'm not sure if the audit system is supposed to work like this or not, but I was reviewing the first posts queue, and was shown what appeared to be a first post by a new user. I opened the question in a new tab, and the answer given was an exact dupe of the accepted answer by a different user, yet wasn't listed as an answer. I was slightly puzzled, thinking maybe the answer I was reviewing had already been deleted, but I went ahead and left a comment saying that it was a an exact dupe of the accepted answer, that the user needed to expand on their answer and provide an explanation why it was better than the accepted answer.

After clicking I'm finished, I was notified that it was audit, and that I failed.

Did I do something wrong, or should I have been clued in to the fact that it was a test, because it was an exact dupe of the accepted answer?

Comment: Urgh. Can't we just [get rid of audits](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5680/5373) already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Posts audits anonymize known-good posts by obfuscating the username, reputation, and badge count. If they didn't, it would be pretty easy to see that it's not really a first post, wouldn't it? ;)

Audits aren't always totally truthful to real posts on the site. The fact that you caught this means you're doing fine. Nothing to worry about.

---

To address your edit, I'm not actually sure what the system wanted from you in this case. Either way, a single failed audit isn't anything to worry about, especially since you seem to be paying attention.

Comment: Actually, by leaving the comment, and not up-voting the question, I apparently failed the audit. I've added that to the question.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Quick edit. I'm less certain about why it was a failed audit.